# Openweathermap API unable to fetch on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, openweathermap

I'm working on an Android app and trying to fetch weather data using the OpenWeatherMap API. My code runs without errors, but I'm not getting the expected data. I've checked my API key, URL, and permissions. Can someone help me troubleshoot and identify what might be going wrong?

```
 package com.example.weatherapp

import android.nfc.Tag
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.weatherapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy{
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    private fun fetchWeatherData() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
            .build().create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val call = retrofit.getWeatherData("delhi", "7df02152b8210edcace6c263468584a7", "metric")

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherApp> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherApp>, response: Response<WeatherApp>) {
                val responseBody = response.body()
                if (response.isSuccessful && responseBody != null) {
                    val temperature = responseBody.main.temp.toString()
                    val humidity=responseBody.main.humidity
                    val sunRise=responseBody.sys.sunrise
                    val sunSet=responseBody.sys.sunset
                    val windSpeed=responseBody.wind.speed
                    val condition=responseBody.weather.firstOrNull()?.main?: "unknown"
                    val maxTemp=responseBody.main.temp_max
                    val minTemp=responseBody.main.temp_min
                    binding.temp.text="$temperature °C"
                    binding.weather.text=condition
                    binding.maxTamp.text="Max Temp: $maxTemp °C"
                    binding.minTemp.text="Min Temp: $minTemp °C"
                    binding.humidity.text="$humidity %"
                    binding.windSpeed.text="$windSpeed m/s"
                    binding.sunRise.text="$sunRise"
                    binding.sunset.text="$sunSet"


                  
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherApp>, t: Throwable) {
                // Handle the failure
            }
        })
    }


}
```

The base URL and query parameters appear to be set up correctly. I'm using Retrofit to make the API call. However, I'm not receiving the expected weather data.

I've also added logging statements for debugging, but they don't seem to provide any insights into the problem.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot and identify what might be going wrong in my code or configuration? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.